# def getLotteryGame(): won't return(True)

Tags: python

In my def getLotteryGame(): Which is suppose to check if the timer runs out and if it does it sorts the players, ranks them, gives them their winnings and stores a note for them and then return True and when it returns True the bot reloads the game making a new round. I tried several ways of trying to get it to return True.  This is the code:

```
def getLotteryGame():
    global pot
    global players
    different = float(time.time() - lotteryStart)
    years = int(different / Point.YEAR)
    days = int((different % Point.YEAR) / Point.DAY)
    hours = int((different % Point.DAY) / Point.HOUR)
    mins = int((different % Point.HOUR) / Point.MINUTE)
    secs = int(different % Point.MINUTE)
    if secs <= 0:
        if len(players) > 0:
            random.shuffle(players)
            ratios = []
            for i in range(-2, len(players) - 2) if i > 0 else range(len(players)):
                if i < 0:
                    ratios.append(1 - (i * 0.33)) # ratio > 1
                else:
                    ratios.append(1 / (1 + (i * 0.33))) # ratio <= 1
                    winnings = [pot * r for r in ratios]
                for m in range(1, len(players)):
                    notes.store("~lottery~", players[m], "The system has placed you "+Point.ordinal(m)+" in the lottery. The lottery awarded you "+winnings+" P$", time.time())
                    alerts.append(players[m])
                    winnings = int(winnings)
                    point = Point.dPoint[players[m]]
                    point = int(point)
                    point = int(point+winnings)
                    Point.dPoint[players[m]] = int(point)
            return(True)
        elif len(players) == 0:
            return(True)
    else:
         return(False)
```

When I wait for the difference to go <= 0 for if secs <= 0. It keeps returning False instead and I'm not sure why.

Comment: You should explain what you are trying to do with that function!

Comment: btw, you can write return statements without the parenthesis: `return True`

Comment: Try printing the value of `secs` and `len(players)` before returning a value.

Comment: Ah okay. Sorry I forgot xD

Comment: It's complicated to understand the indentation of your code, may be you can try to improve your formatting and that will help you see the logic behind it

Comment: What is the code for your `Point` object?

Comment: http://bpaste.net/show/164761/ this is the whole thing

Comment: Lol none of these answers work :/

Answer (score 2):

Your code logic is brokem. `lotteryStart` is defined when the code first runs, as `time.time()`. Later, you find the number of seconds since `lotteryStart`. This number of seconds, might be zero occasionally, and is never going to be less than zero. Since time moves forward, it should always be positive. Thus your code always executes the final `else` statement that returns False.

Comment: I really don't know, it looks more promising, but without knowing what you want to do, it is hard to say. Somewhere you need to decide how long you should wait between the start of the Lottery and the finish. I would suggest scrapping everything to do with hours/days/minutes, etc and just deal with seconds. Once you make it work for an arbitrary number of seconds, you can then introduce minutes/hours back into your code if you feel this is needed. Personally I would leave it as seconds everywhere, and convert those seconds to hours/minutes **only** when I needed to display the time to a user.

Comment: Yeah I fixed it so now only the elif len(player) == 0: works. But the if len(players) > 0 part doesn't though.

Comment: @user3103923 what do you mean it doesn't work? If your code can return True when `len(players)==0` then it should certainly return `True` if `len(players) > 0` unless your code is raising an exception. If it is raising an exception, please post it.

Answer (score 1):

```
different = float(time.time() - lotteryStart)
```

Maybe lotteryStart is a global variable as well as it is not defined anywhere?

Comment: Its a variable above class Point: